# fontawesome embed link says - net::ERR_ABORTED 403

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have this code - long time - for getting fontawesome icons

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/all.css' integrity='sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr' crossorigin='anonymous'>
```

Now, suddenly - it doesn't work
Console says -  `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/all.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403`
my net connection is ok
pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the access to the file is denied. Use `font-awesome` from `cdnjs` instead.

[Link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)

Answer (score 1):

you can try paste `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/all.css` in browser, as I see, the file is inaccessible now

you can try `https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css`